# using facebook client flow to authnticate and login on app/site

Tags: security, authentication, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

Other then the fact that when using facebook's client-flow you get an access token right away, and when using the server-flow you first get an authorization code that you have to exchange for an access token, What is the difference between the two flows and when should I use each of them ?

more specifically can I use client-flow and still be able to securely log a user into my application/site?

At first glance I though that I could take the access_token and id I got on the client (via client-flow), send them to my server and then if a graph api call for that ID and token does not break I can assume I am dealing with this user and log him into my site based on his FB ID.

On second thought it looks to me that If I don't follow the server-flow there is no way to securely use the client id & access_token to log the user into my application/site.

The reason I say this is that another (hacker) app owner that "shares" a user with my app. might take the access_token and and ID he (illegitimately) got for user on his authorization flow, and fake a call to my site with this data causing me to log him in as if he was this user.

Am I missing something here?

Should this not be written in big red letters on the first paragraph of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Oauth 2 (http://oauth.net/2/) is what Facebook uses.  For the most part it is the most secure interface available. If there was a way for a user to take an access token for one app and then use it in another app, then oauth2 will need to be patched (or Facebook oauth2 will need to be patched).

If you think you found a way to hack it, then you should get your $500.00 prize from http://www.facebook.com/whitehat/bounty